# protection level problem, it must be public

Tags: c#

I am trying to make all my classes internal in my project and only few classes to be public which will be accessible from other projects.

"TResponse" is my model and it is internal class. I am having "protection level problem, it must be public" notice. How can I hide my Models to outside but still manage to use internally?

---

```
internal class _DeserializeResponse<TResponse> where TResponse : IResponsable
{
    public TResponse Deserialize(string xmlResponse)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TResponse));

        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xmlResponse))
        {
            var _return = (TResponse)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(sr);
            return _return;
        }
    }
}
```

EDITED *****************************************

This is better sample for you. I noticed that I receive a notification as you can see below, saying that "**inconsistent accessibility return type "MyModel" is less accessible than method "Manager.Test()**"

Apparently I cannot return non-public class from a public method. As I can understand, there is only way to achive this that MyModel should be public and no way to hide it from outside unless I use "**[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]**" attribute as **Legacy Code** suggests.

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace AutoEurope.Concrete
{
    internal class Test<TResponse> where TResponse : ITest
    {
        public TResponse Deserialize(string xmlResponse)
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TResponse));

            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xmlResponse))
            {
                var _return = (TResponse)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(sr);
                return _return;
            }
        }
    }
    internal interface ITest
    {
    }

    internal class MyModel: ITest
    {

    }

    public class Manager
    {
        public MyModel Test() // inconsistent accessibility return type "MyModel" is less accessible than method "Manager.Test()"
        {
            var test = new Test<MyModel>();
            return test.Deserialize("sample");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you call the method? Where does the error occur?

Comment: @T_Bacon sure you can. See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gsh86h

Comment: Please specify the *exact* error message. I doubt that it's really just "protection level problem, it must be public".

Comment: I edited for better explanation

Comment: I made my model classes public and issue resolved. There is no need to hide from outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is just hiding, but you would not mind if someone finds it... Then I recommend using [EditorBrowsableAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: Thank you. It works but I understood than hiding model from outside is not a big problem on my side. So I made my model public. It is not violating anything. My Methods are hidden and thats enough.